# Max number of k-clauses such that no two clauses can be resolved?

Tags: sat, resolution

Let $n$ be the number of variables and $k$ the size of the clauses. What is the maximum number of k-clauses such that no two clauses can be resolved to a smaller (less than $k$) clause.

I will accept an answer for when $n=k$.

I think these are correct:

N | K | Max

n | 1 | n

$(a)$

2 | 2 | 2

$(a \lor b)(\bar a \lor \bar b)$

3 | 3 | 2

$(a \lor b \lor c)(\bar a \lor \bar b \lor \bar c)$

4 | 4 | 8

$(a \lor b \lor c \lor d)(\bar a \lor \bar b \lor c \lor d)(\bar a \lor b \lor \bar c \lor d)(\bar a \lor b \lor c \lor \bar d)(a \lor \bar b \lor \bar c \lor d)(a \lor \bar b \lor c \lor \bar d)(a \lor b \lor \bar c \lor \bar d)(\bar a \lor \bar b \lor \bar c \lor \bar d)$

I didn't find any promising sequences on [Sloanes Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/).

This is related to [How often can a clause cause a conflict](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53602/how-often-can-a-clause-cause-a-conflict)

Rus9384 pointed out I made mistake for n=k=3:

$(\bar a \lor \bar b \lor \bar c)(\bar a \lor b \lor c)(a \lor \bar b \lor c)(a \lor b \lor \bar c)$

Comment: This is not correct for $3$: you need to encode $a\oplus b\oplus c$ just as how you did with $2$ and $4$.

Comment: @rus9384 Do you mean use XOR? I am assuming CNF. All I can use is OR.

Comment: I am saying that XOR translates to an exponentially long CNF. XOR over $n$ variables requires $2^{n-1}$ clauses. For 3 it is 4 clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $0<k\le n$, the maximal size of such a set of clauses is $$\binom nk2^{k-1},$$
i.e., $1/2$ of the number of all $k$-clauses. (I’m assuming a clause cannot contain any variable both positively and negatively.) (For $k=0$, the answer is clearly $1$.)

The problem can be restated as the maximal size of an independent set in a graph whose vertices are $k$-clauses in $n$ variables, and with edges $\{C_0,C_1\}$ such that $C_0$ and $C_1$ resolve to a $(k-1)$-clause. This is equivalent to the condition that $C_0$ and $C_1$ differ just by negating one literal (which implies, in particular, that they have the same set of variables): the resolvent of $C_0$ and $C_1$ includes $k-1$ literals from each clause, hence it has only $k-1$ literals in total iff the contributions from the two clauses are identical.

This graph has $\binom nk$ connected components, each of which consists of clauses that use a particular set of $k$ variables; each component is in turn isomorphic to the Hamming graph with vertex set $\{0,1\}^k$ and edges connecting vertices of Hamming distance $1$ (the vectors in $\{0,1\}^k$ indicate which variables are negated). The independence number of the Hamming graph is well known to be $2^{k-1}$ (for $k>0$): on the one hand, the set of vectors with even Hamming weight forms an independent set of size $2^{k-1}$; on the other hand, the vectors in any independent set must differ in their first $k-1$ coordinates. Of course, the independence number of the whole graph is the sum of independence numbers of its components, thus $\binom nk2^{k-1}$.

This argument gives an explicit set of $\binom nk2^{k-1}$ clauses as a witness: the set of all clauses that have an even number of positive literals (for $n=k$, this is the CNF expansion of $x_1\oplus\dots\oplus x_n$, as rus9384 puts in in the comments).

[NB: If we *do* allow a variable to occur both positively and negatively in a clause, the answer changes to $\frac12\binom{2n}k$ (= $1/2$ of all $k$-clauses) for $k$ odd, and $\frac12\bigl(\binom{2n}k+\binom n{k/2}\bigr)$ for $k$ even, by a similar argument. But given the motivation of the question, I doubt this is the intended interpretation.]