# Max number of m-clauses NOT subsumed by k-clauses

Tags: sat, resolution

This question is releated to:

[Max number of k-clauses such that no two clauses can be resolved?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53777/max-number-of-k-clauses-such-that-no-two-clauses-can-be-resolved)

and

[How often can a clause cause a conflict](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53602/how-often-can-a-clause-cause-a-conflict)

Assume there are $N$ variables and a maximum size set of $k$-clauses such that no two $k$-clauses resolve to a smaller clause.

What is the maximum number of $m$-clauses, where $n \ge m \gt k$, that are NOT subsumed by the $k$-clauses?

I think the answer for $k=2$ is $2(n-k)$.

Assume $N=3$ and $k=2$.

$(a \lor b)(a \lor c)(b \lor c)(\bar a \lor \bar b)(\bar a \lor \bar c)(\bar b \lor \bar c)$

This set of binary clauses subsumes all $3$-clauses. Every $3$-clause must have at least two positive literals or at least two negative literals.

There is a binary clause for every combintation of two positive or two negative literals. A similar argument shows every $m$-clause can be subsumed by a set of $2{N \choose 2}$ binary clauses for any $N$.

I think this set of binary clauses is the worst case for $N=3, k=2$:

$(a \lor \bar b)(a \lor \bar c)(b \lor \bar c)(\bar a \lor b)(\bar a \lor c)(\bar b \lor c)$

This set subsumes any clause where one literal is positive and one literal is negative.

There are two $3$-clauses that are not subsumed: $(a \lor b \lor c)$ and $(\bar a \lor \bar b \lor \bar c)$.

I would like a proof that $2(n-k)$ is the max for $k=2$ and an answer for $k=3$.

---

I realized the question above isn't the question I wanted to ask.

I think I can show that a DPLL-CDCL SAT solver will never create a learned clause that can be subsumed by a clause already in the instance. I want to know if a SAT instance with a lot of binary and 3-clauses subsumes so many larger clauses that the CDCL solver can't find very many larger learned clauses.

Let $N$ be the number of variables. Assume there are $k$ binary clauses. What is the maximum number of $m$-clauses, $N \ge m \gt 2$, that are NOT subsumed by the binary clauses?

I would accept an answer for how many larger clauses are subsumed by a single binary clause. That would allow me to determine how many clauses are subsumed by a set of disjoint binary clauses.

Ideally, I would like to know how may larger clauses are subsumed by a combination of binary and 3-clauses.